# visual studio 2010 change display option

Tags: visual-studio-2010

How can I change all the points before the beginning of the each line, to the default (not display)?
Here is a pics:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Edit menu > Advanced > View White Space. The default keyboard binding in 'general development settings' is Ctrl+R, Ctrl+W.